# rearrange listgroup items in reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I had a listgroup from reactstrap and I want to be able to drag items to rearrange them and change the order after the page has loaded? Is this possible or are listgroups static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactstrap ListGroup does not support drag and drop functionality you have to use other react component for that like `react-drag-list`, `react-draggable-list`, etc 
 [react-drag-list](http://front-ender.me/react-drag-list/examples/simple.html)

[react-draggable-list](https://streakyc.github.io/react-draggable-list/example/)